# ImmutableService requires getRowNodeId() callback to be implemented, your row data need IDs

Tags: ag-grid

I tried to add

```
[deltaRowDataMode]="true"
```

to my grid and called

```
this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);
```

but the code throws the error

```
ag-Grid: ImmutableService requires getRowNodeId() callback to be implemented, your row data need IDs!
```

push../projects/secdo-infra-lib/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/rowModels/clientSide/immutableService.js.ImmutableService.createTransactionForRowData @ immutableService.js:38
push../projects/secdo-infra-lib/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/gridApi.js.GridApi.setRowData @ gridApi.js:151

Looking this up online I have read that getRowNodeId is auto generated if not set so I don't understand why the error is thrown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#delta-row-data)

> For the deltaRowDataMode to work, you must be providing ID's for the
>   row nodes by implementing the getRowNodeId() callback.
>
> The grid works out the delta changes with the following rules:
>
> IF the ID for the new item doesn't have a corresponding item already in the grid THEN it's an 'add'.
>   IF the ID for the new item does have a corresponding item in the grid THEN compare the object references. If the object references are different, it's an update, otherwise it's nothing (excluded from the transaction).
>   IF there are items in the grid for which there are no corresponding items in the new data, THEN it's a 'remove'.

You can implement `getRowNodeId()` in a way that it returns unique ids for each row. e.g.

```
this.getRowNodeId = function(data) {
  return data.id; //id is a field here
};
```

This official [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#example-simple-immutable-store) has more details